# Xamarin Forms - How to select a ListView item when its image is clicked?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a data template coded in xaml where the `ListViewItem` has an `ImageButton`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="George.KeySave.FilesList"
         xmlns:localImg="clr-namespace:George.Image"
         Title="KeySave">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="Flist" ItemSelected="Flist_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,0,0,0">
                        <Label x:Name="SelFileName" Text="{Binding fname}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Blue" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <ImageButton HeightRequest="33" WidthRequest="33" Source="{localImg:Emb ResId=George.Image.deer.png}"
                                     x:Name="delete" Clicked="delete_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

But it fails under these conditions. Suppose I click the name of the second item so that the second item is selected. The problem is if I now click the `ImageButton` of the *first* item, the wrong file will be deleted because the second item is still selected.

This code shows how I handle the `ImageButton.Click` and the `ListView.ItemSelected` events.

```
public partial class FilesList : ContentPage
{
    private void delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("delete file", $"{TdelFile.fname}", "ok");
    }

    listdatas TdelFile;
    private void Flist_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var delFile = e.SelectedItem as listdatas;
        TdelFile = delFile;
    }
}
```

**The problem:** The incorrect file pops up when I click the `ImageButton` of the first item while the second item is selected.

[image: deleting the wrong file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code is written now, you would look at the `sender` argument of your `ImageButton.Click` handler which will *be* the `ImageButton`. The `BindingContext` of the `ImageButton` will be the item itself and you can set `FList.SelectedItem` from that. Then, the user is given a confirmation prompt before proceeding (or not) with the file deletion.

```
private async void delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ImageButton imageButton)
    {
        Flist.SelectedItem = imageButton.BindingContext;
        var fileName = ((DataModel)Flist.SelectedItem).fname;
        if (await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
            "delete file",
            fileName, accept: "OK",
            cancel: "CANCEL"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"DELETED {fileName}");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled!");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Ok-Cancel prompt]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/select_programatically_from_image.git) this sample.

Comment: It looks as though you already have a data model because you're binding the `fname` property . It would be more MVVM to change your xaml to `ImageButton Command="{Binding DeleteFileWithPromptCommand}` and move the implementation from the `ContentPage` to the model. I added a branch to the same [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/select_programatically_from_image.git) that answers your question using the MVVM approach.